# Maven compiling with dependencies not in POM

Tags: java, maven, servlets, pom.xml

I'm trying to build a Maven project from work, which has servlet-api 3.1.0 as a provided dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But then fails to compile because it cannot find `getRequestURL()` from `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`.

Later, I found out it's using an older version of servlet-api which I **never** included in my POM:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.2/servlet-api-2.2.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.2/servlet-api-2.2.jar (41 kB at 63 kB/s)
```

Maybe that version of servlet-api is comming from a dependency, but I don't know from which one, they are a lot.

How can I override that version with the one I added in the project's POM?

Comment: Have you tried running `mvn dependency:tree`? That should show you which dependency it's coming from and then you can fix that as a first step

Comment: As @mattfreake said, it could be a **transient** dependency.

Comment: *transitive ...

Comment: @mattfreake I didn't know that command, thanks! I found out `commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.3` depends on the older servlet API. I think I could replace it with something else, but in case I couldn't, how could I handle this version conflict?

Comment: I just tried to add `<type>jar</type>` to the `commons-configuration` dependency to see if it used just the jar file instead of the whole POM thing, but the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try couple of things.

1. Try mvn dependency:tree to see if it is getting downloaded as part of another dependency.
2. If you don’t see the dependency getting downloaded as part of another dependency, clean you local repository( it might be inside .m2 directory) and do a clean install of your application.
3. you can also share your pom.xml so that others can take a look and help.

Comment: Just tried to `dependency:tree` my project and found out `commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.3` depends on the older servlet API. I just tried to add `<type>jar</type>` to the `commons-configuration` dependency to see if it used just the jar file instead of the whole POM thing, but the same. Do you know any other way to achieve that?

Comment: Btw this is the whole dependency trace: `commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.3` --> `commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.2` --> `javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.2`

Comment: You can use exclusions in your pom to exclude the jar. You can follow the url if you want to learn more: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html